# Databinding and then calling from another class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My purpose is to add a textblock to my main UI window, of which text will be updated if needed. For that, in my UIWindow xaml I did like this:

```
<Window x:Class="UIDesigner.UIWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:UIDesigner"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:UIDesigner.Controls"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"        
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    Title="GUI"
    Height="1000" Width="1400"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Icon="Resources/Images/Logo.png"        
    >

<Grid Margin="0">
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">

    <GroupBox Header="Console" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,590,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="consoleWindow" IsEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                >
        <TextBlock x:Name="myConsoleWindowTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=consoleText}"/>
    </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

This is the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace UIDesigner
{
    public partial class UIWindow : Window
    {
        public UIWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }


        private string _consoleText;
        public string consoleText
        {
            get{ return _consoleText;}
            set
            {
                _consoleText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("consoleText");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my main class, I call this `UIWindow` like this:

```
namespace UIDesigner
{
    public partial class Main : Window
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void LoginButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {        
            var myUIWindow = new UIWindow();                
            myUIWindow.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(UIWindow_PropertyChanged);

            myUIWindow.consoleText = "Hello User!";
            myUIWindow.ShowDialog();

            this.Close();

    }

    private void LoginButton_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {   
    }

    static void UIWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something Changed!");
        MessageBox.Show(e.PropertyName);
    }

    }

}
```

Now I have two problems here:

**First**, when my UI window starts, I indeed received two message boxes, saying "something changed" followed by "consoleText". So that means the `consoleText` is changed successfully. But after my UIWindow shows up, the textblock is empty, I cannot see "Hello User!" there. Seems like `Text="{Binding Path=consoleText}` part is not working correctly in my xaml file.

**Second and most importantly**, I want to change the `consoleText` in another different class, namely in `DesignerCanvas.Commands.cs`. For that I couldn't figure out any solution. I want something like this in my `DesignerCanvas.Commands.cs`:

```
namespace UIDesigner
{
    public partial class DesignerCanvas
    {

        private void changeConsoleOutput(string updatedConsoleText)
        {
            myUIWindow.consoleText = updatedConsoleText;  //obviously, this is not working
        }
    }
}
```

Any kind of suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.First of two set the value in UI just add below one line

in constructor of UIWindow class

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

//because only specifying property consoletext, it will not able to know where to find consoletext.

2.u can find that UIwindow in  App.Current.Windows and cast it to UIWindow type and then can 
access the property.

```
foreach(Window win in App.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (win as UIWindow != null)
                {
                    (win as UIWindow).consoletext = updatedConsoleText;
                }
            }
```

For second problem

Change

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myConsoleWindowTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=consoleText}"/
```

To

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myConsoleWindowTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/
```

and

in UIWindow constructor  set

```
myConsoleWindowTextBlock.Datacontext=consoleText;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. With your help, I solved my first problem and half of the second. Because I can also see the message box after I change consoleText in another class, but the textBlock is not updating, displaying "Hello User" but not the new message. I tried to add "this.DataContext = this" also to its constructor. Could you point it out? Thank you.

Comment: In my second question, I was expecting to see "updatedConsoleText" in my textblock. But it shows "Hello User" after start and not updating the text when I call the "changeConsoleOutput" function.

Comment: have you check that your window level property you are able to access or not

Comment: yes, I can access to my window level property, and I am sure that "consoleText" is changed into the "updatedConsoleText" after calling function "changeConsoleOutput". But the problem is, the textblock is not refreshing. Any suggestion?

Comment: I see a lot of nasty code behind here ;) But a tip you may set your datacontext directly in your xaml aswell. <Window.DataContext>local:YourViewModel</Window.DataContext>. Using galasoft mvvm light you do this in the viewmodel locator, which is nice because you can easily change designmode and regular mode datacontext

Comment: @Stian: thank you for your suggestion. I will alo try out your mentioned method. Meanwhile, I just solved my second problem. The point is, all those "NotifyPropertyChanged" related part should be written into another class of form "public partial class UIWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged", and that solved all the rest :)

Comment: @E_learner: Great! You either need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or use a dp when binding in your code, so changes to these properties will signal a redraw, when chaning the properties/dp from your code.